# Priority (precedence) of the logical operators (order of operations) for NOT, AND, OR in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-precedence, boolean-expression

As far as I know, in C & C++, the priority sequence for NOT AND & OR is NOT>AND>OR. But this doesn't seem to work in a similar way in Python. I tried searching for it in the Python documentation and failed (Guess I'm a little impatient.). Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Can you give an example where the operator precedence doesn't work like you think it does?

Comment: not is greater than and is greater than or

Answer (score 149):

It's `NOT`, `AND`, `OR`, from highest to lowest according to the documentation on
[Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Here is the complete precedence table, lowest precedence to highest. A row has the same precedence and groups from left to right

```
 0. :=
 1. lambda
 2. if – else
 3. or
 4. and
 5. not x
 6. in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==
 7. |
 8. ^
 9. &
10. <<, >>
11. +, -
12. *, @, /, //, %
13. +x, -x, ~x
14. **
14. await x
15. x[index], x[index:index], x(arguments...), x.attribute
16. (expressions...), [expressions...], {key: value...}, {expressions...}
```

Comment: Note that `**` has some exceptions noted in a footnote when it comes to precedence over arithmetic operators.

Comment: This confuses the mathematician in me: in arithmetic, we would say it has precedence over arithmetic operators. On its right, the `**` operator does not have precedence over arithmetic operations, but it has on its left... For example, `5*2**2 == 5*(2**2)`. However it is right to say that `2**-1 == 2**(-1)`.

Comment: @PhilMacKay - it might seem, that e.g. the minus is part of the `int` literal, but when parsing it with `ast` it's not the case - it's `UnaryOp` with `USub` and `1` as operand. The real reason is, there is no other way to parse it. I.e. `2**` is not a correct left operand for binary minus. Thus "exponentiation priority exception", but "only on the right".

Answer (score 44):

You can do the following test to figure out the precedence of `and` and `or`.

First, try `0 and 0 or 1` in python console

If `or` binds first, then we would expect `0` as output.

In my console, `1` is the output. It means `and` either binds first or equal to `or` (maybe expressions are evaluated from left to right).

Then try `1 or 0 and 0`.

If `or` and `and` bind equally with the built-in left to right evaluation order, then we should get `0` as output.

In my console, `1` is the output. Then we can conclude that `and` has higher priority than `or`.

Comment: More explicitly, the expressions are evaluated as: `((0 and 0) or 1)` and `(1 or (0 and 0))`

Comment: However, in the second expression, the `(0 and 0)` is never evaluated as `(exp1 or exp2)` directly return if `exp1` is `True`.
Similarly in the first expression, the `and 0` part is never evaluated as `exp1 and exp2` directly return if `exp1` is `False`.

Answer (score 22):

`not` binds tighter than `and` which binds tighter than `or` as stated in the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 6):

Of the boolean operators the precedence, from weakest to strongest, is as follows:

1. `or`
2. `and`
3. `not x`
4. `is not`; `not in`

Where operators are of equal precedence evaluation proceeds from left to right.

Comment: Sorry your #2 is technically correct but still very misleading. First of all, the doc doesn't seem to change. Secondly, your opinion #2 (suggesting `and` & `not x` is evaluated from left to right) is technically equivalent to the official effect, but that is simply because when in "cond1 and not cont2", python has to calculate cont2 first by default.

Comment: Thanks @RayLuo, but it wasn't  even _technically_ correct.  I was placing meaning in the incorrectly rendered lines dividing the rows in that table.  Looking at the 2.7 doc _today_ `or` and `and` appear to be in the same cell using _Firefox_ but not _Opera_ .  The difference in precedence between `or` and `and` is obvious (eg.  `1 or 0 and 0` vs `(1 or 0) and 0`) that between `and` and `not x` not so much for the reason you give.  I'll repair my answer to reflect what the documentation _actually_ says.

Answer (score 6):

Some simple examples; note the operator precedence (not, and, or); parentheses to assist human-interpretability.

```py
a = 'apple'
b = 'banana'
c = 'carrots'

if c == 'carrots' and a == 'apple' and b == 'BELGIUM':
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
# False
```

Similarly:

```py
if b == 'banana'
True

if c == 'CANADA' and a == 'apple'
False

if c == 'CANADA' or a == 'apple'
True

if c == 'carrots' and a == 'apple' or b == 'BELGIUM'
True

# Note this one, which might surprise you:
if c == 'CANADA' and a == 'apple' or b == 'banana'
True

# ... it is the same as:
if (c == 'CANADA' and a == 'apple') or b == 'banana':
True

if c == 'CANADA' and (a == 'apple' or b == 'banana'):
False

if c == 'CANADA' and a == 'apple' or b == 'BELGIUM'
False

if c == 'CANADA' or a == 'apple' and b == 'banana'
True

if c == 'CANADA' or (a == 'apple' and b == 'banana')
True

if (c == 'carrots' and a == 'apple') or b == 'BELGIUM'
True

if c == 'carrots' and (a == 'apple' or b == 'BELGIUM')
True

if a == 'apple' and b == 'banana' or c == 'CANADA'
True

if (a == 'apple' and b == 'banana') or c == 'CANADA'
True

if a == 'apple' and (b == 'banana' or c == 'CANADA')
True

if a == 'apple' and (b == 'banana' and c == 'CANADA')
False

if a == 'apple' or (b == 'banana' and c == 'CANADA')
True
```

Answer (score 2):

There is *no good reason* for Python to have *other* priority sequence of those operators than *well established one* in (almost) all other programming languages, including C/C++.

You may find it in *The Python Language Reference*, part 6.16 - Operator precedence, downloadable (for the current version and packed with all other standard documentation) from https://docs.python.org/3/download.html, or read it online here: [6.16. Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

But there is still something in Python which can mislead you: The *result* of `and` and `or` operators may be *different* from `True` or `False` - see [6.11 Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) in the same document.

Answer (score 0):

`not` > `and`

```py
print(~0&0) # 0
```

`and` > `or`

```py
print(0&0|1) # 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Expression `1 or 1 and 0 or 0` returns `1`. Looks like we have the same priority, almost same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).