# nested "and/or" if statements

Tags: python, list, boolean-logic, nested-if

I am working on code which creates a list and then applies both the "or" and "and" conditions to do further action:

```
a= ["john", "carlos", "22", "70"]

if (("qjohn" or "carlos") in a) and (("272" or "70") in a):
    print "true"
else:
    print "not true"
```

output:

```
not true
```

when I do this:

```
a= ["john", "carlos", "22", "70"]

if ("qjohn" or "cdarlos" in a) and ("272" or "d70" in a):
    print "true"
else:
    print "not true"
```

output is `"true"`

What I am not getting is `**carlos and 70**` should be equal to true but it's printing "not true". What is the cause of this error? Thanks

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but deals with the same basic issue: [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both approaches are incorrect. Keep in mind *or* is a short-circuit operator so it's not doing what you think it does:

> it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false.

However, non-empty strings are always `True`, so that the first case only checks for the containment of the first non-empty string while the second never performs the containment check with `in` at all, therefore, it is always `True`.

What you want is:

```
if ("qjohn" in a or "carlos" in a) and ("272"  in a or "70" in a):
   ...
```

If the items to test were longer, you could avoid repeating the `or` by using `any` which like `or` also short-circuits once one of the items test `True`:

```
if any(x in a for x in case1) and any(x in a for x in case2):
   ...
```

Comment: Could be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python

Answer (score 1):

```
b = set(a)
if {"qjohn", "carlos"} & b and {"272", "70"} & b:
    ....
```

The conditional is `True` if the intersection of the sets results in a non-empty set (membership test) - testing the truthiness of a non-empty set is quite pythonic in this regard.

---

Alternatively, using `set.intersection`:

```
if {"qjohn", "carlos"}.insersection(a) and {"272", "70"}.insersection(a):
    ....
```

Comment: If you use the `intersection` method, there's no need to precompute the set `b`; the method can take any iterable as its argument. `{"qjohn", "carlos"}.intersection(a)`, etc. (Whether you would want to do this depends on how big `a` is in the first place.)

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I'm of the opinion that this is an underrated solution.

Answer (score 0):

The both are incorrect. You understood the logic false.

`("qjohn" or "carlos") in a` is equivalent to `"qjohn" in a`

and

`"qjohn" or "cdarlos" in a` is equivalent to `"qjohn" or ("cdarlos" in a)`