# Python: How does python executes multiple boolean in one statement?

Tags: python, boolean-logic

With following condition, what should Python return?
In which sequence the condition will get executed?

> True or False and False and True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Dean Dumitru has said and like it said in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python); the AND has a higher precedence than OR.

Hence, your condition could be rewritten in this way:

```
True or ((False and False) and True) -> True or (False and True) -> True or False -> TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

AND has a higher precedence than OR.

True or False and False and True -> True or TRUE and True -> True or TRUE -> TRUE.

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Comment: Can you please explain bit more that in your first step, how did you derive -> True or True and True?

As you previously mentioned that AND has a higher precedence hence my original question can be treated in either way as follows;
True or (False and False) and True
or
True or False and (False and True)

Comment: False and False is equal to False with a logical conjunction (AND); look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction

Comment: The expression will be executed from left to right in the order of operators precedence. As @toom501 said below. I personally always use () when combining them.

Comment: Also might want to note that in this example it'll actually short-circuit after seeing `True or` and return True regardless of what follows the `True or`