# Please can anyone tell me why the output is like this ? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner programmer in python and i dont know why the input of this code isnt as i expect it to be:

[my input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iglG7.png)

I am beginner programmer in python and i dont know why the input of this code isnt as i expect it to be:

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    #the number of valid smiley faces in array/list
    smileys_count = 0
    for character in arr:
        if len(character) == 2:
            if character[0] == ":" or character[0] == ";" and character[2] == ")" or character[2] == "D":
                smileys_count += 1
        if len(character) == 3:
            if character[0] == ":" or character[0] == ";" and character[2] == ")" or character[2] == "D" and character[2] == "-" or character[2] == "~":
                smileys_count +=1

    return(smileys_count)
```

and the output is this :

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjQpm.png)

Comment: Remember that the second character in a string has an index of 1, not 2.

Comment: if `len(character) == 2` then `character[2]` will result in an exception

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should paste your code in the question, not link to a png snapshot.

Comment: Thank you .Yes I tried to but I wanted  you to know what is the challange assigment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the logical operator precedence problem: `and` has a higher priority than `or`, much like `*` has a precedence over `+`. You should use parentheses.

```
if len(character) == 2:
  if (character[0] == ":" or character[0] == ";") and (character[1] == ")" or character[1] == "D"):
    smileys_count += 1
```

etc.

See also [Priority of the logical statements NOT AND & OR in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python).

Comment: but the `len(character)==2` meaning the indices are just `0 and 1` so how will `character[2]` work?

Comment: but it says that the len is 3 in that instance

Answer (score 1):

You missed parenthesis, when you mix in a sentence AND/OR, you usually need parenthesis:

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    #the number of valid smiley faces in array/list
    smileys_count = 0
    for character in arr:
        if len(character) == 2:
            if (character[0] == ":" or character[0] == ";") and (character[1] == ")" or character[1] == "D"):
                smileys_count += 1
        if len(character) == 3:
            if (character[0] == ":" or character[0] == ";") and (character[1] == ")" or character[1] == "D") and (character[2] == "-" or character[2] == "~"):
                smileys_count +=1

    return(smileys_count)
```

Also, your indexes are wrong

Comment: No they are not wrong i just wrote them in weird order because the character - and ~ are in the middle of the string if strings len is 3