# Does ''not'' affect the whole if statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, negation

Basically my question is does saying `not` affect the whole `if` statement, even if I added an `or` or `and` in it, or does it affecting only the part that does not begin with an `or` or `and`?

**EDIT**:

Some people tried to send me another similar question(thanks for the help!), but it was talking about the hierarchy, while I was talking about whether or whether not the `not` affects the whole if-statement.

Comment: Operator precedence: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority of the logical statements NOT AND & OR in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python)

Comment: `not` is an operator that affects an expression according to the rules of precedence.

Answer (score 1):

So the way python statements work is that the `not` will only effect the next true/false statement it encounters. `not a and b` would look for a case where a is false and b is true, while `not (a and b)` would look for a case where both `a and b` are not true at the same time. You could even do `b and not a` and that would give an identical result to `not a and b`

Comment: While `b and not a` might yield the same result as `not a and b`, they are not identical. Python has short-circuit boolean operators: `and` is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is true.

Comment: @jarmod true, ill edit it to make it a bit more clear

Comment: You wrote NAND (`not (a and b)`), but you're describing NOR (return true when both a and b are false).