# Python multiple 'OR' 'AND' conditions without parenthesis behaviour

Tags: python, if-statement

The fooliwng code:

```
def foo(arg):
    return arg==arg[::-1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (foo(['A', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'A']) or foo(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) and foo([1, 2, 3, 1]))
```

will print `True` - why?

why the behavior is like:

```
   print (foo(['A', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'A']) or (foo(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']) and foo([1, 2, 3, 1])))
```

And not like:

```
   print ((foo(['A', 'V', 'I', 'V', 'A']) or foo(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])) and foo([1, 2, 3, 1]))
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: `and` has a higher predecence than `or`. `a OR b AND c` would be equivalent, in term of predecences to : `a + b * c`. In case of doubts, always use parenthesis

Comment: The question is moot, you should always use parentheses in such conditionals -- don't guess, don't assume and don't rely on how you think it should work. Its too ambiguous to a reader of your code (including your future self) without parentheses -- even if its behaving the way you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority of the logical statements NOT AND & OR in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR`, check [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).