# Wrong string is being returned on a range of values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding and have been trying to figure out why my code isn't working right.

```
credit_score = int(input('What is your credit score? '))
income = int(input('What is your annual income? '))
good_credit = credit_score>= 400
k = (20*50)

high_income = income>=250000
medium_income = high_income>income>= 70000
low_income = income<70000

if high_income and good_credit or medium_income and good_credit:
  loan = True
  if loan:
    loan = 'approved'
else:
  loan = 'not approved'
  

print(f'Your loan is {loan}')
```

The medium income variable falls between 70,000 and 250,000. What my code is supposed to do is return the string 'approved' when the inputted credit value is greater than or equal to 400 and the income falls between 70,000 and 250,000.

But every time I run it and put in the medium-income values it consistently returns 'not approved', which should only be returned if a low-income value is entered with a high credit value. However, if I enter a high credit value and a high-income value the code works just fine and returns 'approved'.

```
What is your credit score? 900
What is your annual income? 90000
Your loan is not approved?
```

With these values, it should return 'approved'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority of the logical statements NOT AND & OR in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python)

Comment: `high_income` is a boolean, not a threshold to compare against `income`. You want `medium_income = not_high_income and income >= 70000`.

Comment: it returning "not approved" because ```high_income``` is False

Comment: @Thisbitchstoopid your condition can be simplified to `if good_credit and not low_income:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
high_income = income>=250000
medium_income = high_income>income>= 70000
low_income = income<70000
```

You create `high_income` which is `True` or `False` depending on user input, then you use this in comparison

```
high_income>income>= 70000
```

which mean depending on user input is `True>income>= 70000` or `False>income>= 70000`. `True` and `False` when used in numeric comparison does act as `1` and `0` thus they become `1>income>= 70000` or `0>income>= 70000` therefore `medium_income` is always `False`.

Comment: Holy shit thank you, I didn't that True and False had int values as well!

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
medium_income = high_income>income>= 70000
```

Did you mean to put 250000?
Because of that error, medium_income will be False for 90K also.

Also please get in habit of not using magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some brackets to your if statement for readability and to ensure it does what you intended. As it stands, `or` will be evaluated first, so your conditions will be

```
high_income and (good_credit or medium_income) and good_credit
```

which isn't what you intended it to be.

Your calculation of `medium_income` also appears to be incorrect. It appears that you intended it to be

```
medium_income = 250000>income>= 70000
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using the `high_income` object which is a boolean to compare for the `mid_income`. Also, consider adding brackets around the logical expression.

Try this working code:

```
credit_score = int(input('What is your credit score? '))
income = int(input('What is your annual income? '))
good_credit = credit_score>= 400
k = (20*50)

high_income = income >= 250000
medium_income = 250000 > income >= 70000
low_income = income < 70000
if (high_income and good_credit) or (medium_income and good_credit):
  loan = 'approved'
else:
  loan = 'not approved'

print(f'Your loan is {loan}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `high_income` as a threshold against which `income` can be compared, not the boolean value that it is. Since `high_income == False`, your definition of `medium_income` becomes

```
medium_income = False > income >= 70000
```

This is legal, because `bool` is a subclass of `int` and `False == 0`. As a result, `medium_income` is `False`, because `0` is not greater than `income`.

Instead, you want

```
medium_income = not high_income and medium_income >= 70000
```

If you want to store the thresholds, I suggest something like

```
 high_income = 250_000
 medium_income = 70_000

 has_high_income = income >= high_income
 has_medium_income = high_income > income >= medium_income
 has_low_income = medium_income > income

 has_good_credit = credit_score >= 400

# if has_good_credit and (has_high_income or has_medium_income):
if has_high_income and has good_credit or has_medium_income and has_good_credit:
    loan = 'approved'
else:
    loan = 'not approved'
```