# Why does this function return a different value?

Tags: python

Given a day of the week encoded as `0=Sun, 1=Mon, 2=Tue, ...6=Sat`, and a `boolean` indicating if we are on vacation, return a string of the form "7:00" indicating when the alarm clock should ring.

Weekdays, the alarm should be "7:00" and on the weekend it should be "10:00". Unless we are on vacation -- then on weekdays it should be "10:00" and weekends it should be "off"

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if not vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "7:00"
  if not vacation and day==0 or day==6:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and day==0 or day==6:
    return "off"
```

Why does `alarm_clock(6, False) → '10:00'` but `alarm_clock(6, True) → '10:00'` instead of `'off'`?

I know the correct answer but I'm still confused to why my initial logic is off.

Comment: You might want to read about operator precedence. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence
The operator "and" is getting executing first. You can put parantheses around the day == 0 or day == 6 condition.

Comment: Python evaluates `and` conditions before `or`. Put parentheses around your `or` conditions to force them to be evaluated before the `and`. In other words, in Python, `False and False or True` is evaluated as `(False and False) or True`, which is `True`, but `False and (False or True)` would be `False`.

Answer (score 3):

The condition that is failing you:

```
if not vacation and day==0 or day==6:
```

You *think* the above means:

```
if not vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
```

but it *actually* does this:

```
if (not vacation and day==0) or day==6:
```

That is because the operator `and` has higher precedence than `or`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for example.

Comment: That was exactly what I was going to post! Anyway +1

Comment: Ok I understand that writing: if not vacation and day==0 or day==6: inadvertently assigns (alarm_clock(6,True)) as '10:00' but why does it also assign (alarm_clock(6,False)) as '10:00' aswell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `or` like that, try with `in`:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if not vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "7:00"
  if not vacation and day in [0, 6]:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and day in [0, 6]:
    return "off"
```

Example:

```
print(alarm_clock(6, True))
```

Output:

```
off
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add parenthesis as follows:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if not vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "7:00"
  if not vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
    return "off"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to concat the `or` statement within your logic operator test like

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if not vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "7:00"
  if not vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
    return "off"
```

otherwise `not vacation and day==0 or day==6` would get True for both cases, as the `or day==6` part is always `True`.

`print(alarm_clock(6,False))`

> 10:00

`print(alarm_clock(6,True))`

> off

Comment: Ok I understand that writing: 

if not vacation and day==0 or day==6:

inadvertently assigns (alarm_clock(6,True)) as '10:00'

but why does it also assign (alarm_clock(6,False)) as '10:00' aswell?

Comment: AND is proceeded before OR, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python) for further explanation.

Comment: Without parenthesis, if not vacation and day==0 or day==6: return"10:00" is processed as "False and False or True" but alarm_clock(6, False) → '10:00' . Wouldn't  "if vacation and (day==0 or day==6): return 'off' " assign it as "off" ?

Answer (score 0):

This statement is actually evaluating as:

```
if (not vacation and day==0) or day==6:
```

Because python evaluates `and` before `or`.
By putting `vacation` as `True` and `day=6`, both the arguments evaluate to `False` because `not True` is False and `day` is not equal to 6. So `and` evaluated to False

Next, it moves to `or day==6`. And it notices that it is in-fact valid. So it goes to execute the statements under it.

So it returns `'10:00'`.

---

A tip:
Instead of using different `if....if....if`if blocks, use `if....elif....elif....else` statement

Answer (score -1):

add parenthesis between your ORs and AND
you must change your code as follow:

```
def alarm_clock(day, vacation):
  if not vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "7:00"
  if not vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and 1<=day<=5:
    return "10:00"
  if vacation and (day==0 or day==6):
    return "off"
```

Comment: How does this add anything to the answers already made?