# Order of boolean operators

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-statements

Which is the order of the following expression with boolean operators?

```
(condition1)|(condition2)&(condition3)
```

How to read it?

Comment: [This chart](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) gives order of operations.

Comment: Note those are [_bitwise_ operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations), do you actually want `and` and `or`?

Comment: Both & (and) and | (or) and involed. I asked about the order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority of the logical statements NOT AND & OR in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-statements-not-and-or-in-python)