# Evaluating a compund expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
z=2
y=1
```

I have the expression:

```
x = y<z or z>y and y>z or z<y
```

Can somebody explain how this evaluates to True?

Comment: [mre] - add print statements

Comment: Most expressions are compound of smaller expressions. What you wanted to ask is how interleaved `and` and `or` expressions are associated when chained in a single expression, causing the minimal reproducible example of `True or True and False or False` to return `True`. So at the end this is a duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-of-the-logical-operators-not-and-or-in-python

Answer (score 3):

```
z=2
y=1

y<z(True) or z>y(True) and y>z(False) or z<y(False)

True OR True AND False OR False
```

`True AND False` will be evaluated first(as `AND` has higher precedence over `OR`) ;

they come out to be `False`

Now,  `True OR True AND False OR False` reduces to:

```
True OR False OR False
```

So, the final output will be `True`