# Why is (true or false and false) true?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is this printing 'yes'? I don't understand why. I understand that x or y returns true, but x and z should return false, or is the order it compares different?

```
x=True
y=False
z=False
if(x or y and z):
 print ("yes")
else:
 print("no")
```

Comment: `and` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `or` so you have `x or (y and z)`.

Comment: Always use parentheses to specify precedence of operators. 'And' has a higher precedence than 'or'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Priority (precedence) of the logical operators (order of operations) for NOT, AND, OR in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679272/priority-precedence-of-the-logical-operators-order-of-operations-for-not-an)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `and` [has a higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `or`, so it is equivalent to:

```
True or (False and False)
```

Which is:

```
True or False
```

which is:

```
True
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `and` has higher precedence than `or` so it's prioritized when checking the logic of the condition. The condition is essentially equivalent to

```
x or (y and z)
```

You can learn more about Python operators precedence [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, and has higher precedence than or. So when you write x or y and z, it is actually evaluated as x or (y and z).

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence rules in Python, it's the same as:

```py
if x or (y and z):
```

Thus:

```py
if True or (False and False):
```