# Not being able to find empty strings in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, function, if-statement

Learning to program in python. I am trying to make an XOX game using turtle. I made a function to check if there is any X(x) or O(y) in a list that I am placing X or O if there are any.
The function is working all well until I am trying to find if there are no empty quotation marks in the list but I guess that it is not working as I suppose it to work.

Where part of the problem appears:

```
from turtle import *
list1 = [""] * 9

if (
# If there are no empty strings in the list, decide a draw. 
        not list1[0] == ""
        and not list1[1] == ""
        and not list1[2] == ""
        and not list1[3] == ""
        and not list1[4] == ""
        and not list1[5] == ""
        and not list1[6] == ""
        and not list1[7] == ""
        and not list1[8] == ""
    ):
        print("It's a tie.")
        replay()
```

The whole function:

```
from turtle import *
list1 = [""] * 9

def goplace(x, y):
    pencolor("blue")
    sq_1 = 0 < x < 1 and 0 < y < 1
    sq_2 = 0 < x < 1 and 1 < y < 2
    sq_3 = 0 < x < 1 and 2 < y < 3
    sq_4 = 1 < x < 2 and 0 < y < 1
    sq_5 = 1 < x < 2 and 1 < y < 2
    sq_6 = 1 < x < 2 and 2 < y < 3
    sq_7 = 2 < x < 3 and 0 < y < 1
    sq_8 = 2 < x < 3 and 1 < y < 2
    sq_9 = 2 < x < 3 and 2 < y < 3
    count_x = 0
    count_y = 0
    for item_x in list1:
        if item_x == "x":
            count_x += 1
    for item_y in list1:
        if item_y == "y":
            count_y += 1
    if count_x <= count_y:
        if sq_1:
            if list1[0] == "":
                list1[0] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(0, 0)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_2:
            if list1[1] == "":
                list1[1] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(0, 1)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_3:
            if list1[2] == "":
                list1[2] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(0, 2)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_4:
            if list1[3] == "":
                list1[3] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(1, 0)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_5:
            if list1[4] == "":
                list1[4] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(1, 1)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_6:
            if list1[5] == "":
                list1[5] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(1, 2)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_7:
            if list1[6] == "":
                list1[6] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(2, 0)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_8:
            if list1[7] == "":
                list1[7] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(2, 1)
            else:
                return
        elif sq_9:
            if list1[8] == "":
                list1[8] = "x"
                print(list1)
                draw_x(2, 2)
            else:
                return
    if not (
        list1[0] == list1[1] == list1[2] == "x"
        or list1[3] == list1[4] == list1[5] == "x"
        or list1[6] == list1[7] == list1[8] == "x"
        or list1[0] == list1[4] == list1[8] == "x"
        or list1[2] == list1[4] == list1[6] == "x"
        or list1[0] == list1[1] == list1[2] == "y"
        or list1[3] == list1[4] == list1[5] == "y"
        or list1[6] == list1[7] == list1[8] == "y"
        or list1[0] == list1[4] == list1[8] == "y"
        or list1[2] == list1[4] == list1[6] == "y"
    ):
        r_place()

    if list1[0] == list1[1] == list1[2] == "x":
        print("Player won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[3] == list1[4] == list1[5] == "x":
        print("Player won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[6] == list1[7] == list1[8] == "x":
        print("Player won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[0] == list1[1] == list1[2] == "y":
        print("Computer won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[3] == list1[4] == list1[5] == "y":
        print("Computer won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[6] == list1[7] == list1[8] == "y":
        print("Computer won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[0] == list1[4] == list1[8] == "y":
        print("Computer won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[2] == list1[4] == list1[6] == "y":
        print("Computer won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[0] == list1[4] == list1[8] == "x":
        print("Player won!")
        replay()
    elif list1[2] == list1[4] == list1[6] == "x":
        print("Player won!")
        replay()
    if (
        not list1[0] == ""
        and not list1[1] == ""
        and not list1[2] == ""
        and not list1[3] == ""
        and not list1[4] == ""
        and not list1[5] == ""
        and not list1[6] == ""
        and not list1[7] == ""
        and not list1[8] == ""
    ):
        print("It's a tie.")
        replay()
```

I tried using "!=", "and", "not, in, "None", " '' " instead of == "" and tried just list1[] but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Simplify: `if all(x != "" for x in list1)`.

Comment: In general, don't use `not x == y`, use `x != y`.

Comment: What if `x` is exactly equal to an integer? None of the conditions like `0 < x < 1` will be true. You need to use something like `0 <= x <= 1` so exact integers are included.

Comment: It works for me: https://ideone.com/JYc9iT

Comment: Doesn't [`not` take priority over `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679309/378779), so `not list[1] == ""` really means `(not list[1]) == ""`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `if all(x != "" for x in list1)` and other suggestions didn't work for me.

Comment: In what way is it failing? Does it say it's a tie when it isn't, or not say it's a tie when it is?

Comment: See ny link, it shows that it works correct for both ties and non-ties.

Comment: Another thing: Don't use recursion in place of looping.

Comment: The thing is this function works every time user clicks the turtle screen, and it's under a while command. Under the replay() function there is exit() function to stop while while function. So it doesn't say anything (I guess because it can't detect if statement) but gets stuck in the while loop.

Comment: Make a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: While trying to make a minimal reproducible example I found out the problem. The problem was that the code came after
'if not (
        list1[0] == list1[1] == list1[2] == "x"
        or list1[3] == list1[4] == list1[5] == "x"... '

I fixed it by changing their place. Thank you all for helping.

Comment: @Barmar: Even simpler: If the `list` always contains strings, then you can just do `if not any(list1):` and avoid a genexpr entirely; `any` will truth test all the strings, returning `True` if they're all empty, and `False` if at least one is non-empty, and `not` will invert it to get the same effect with no Python level iteration code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger did you invert your logic there?  `any` will return `True` if any are non-empty, and `False` if they're all empty.

Comment: @nadirnesrin and that's the power of the minimal reproducible example.  You aren't the first person to solve your own problem by doing it; it's a very powerful technique that would do you well to perfect.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yeah, my brain was off last night. Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `!=` to test equality of the list item versus the empty string `""`

Such as:

```
list1 = ["a"] * 9

# If there are no empty strings in the list, decide a draw. 
if (
    list1[0] != ""
    and list1[1] != ""
    and list1[2] != ""
    and list1[3] != ""
    and list1[4] != ""
    and list1[5] != ""
    and list1[6] != ""
    and list1[7] != ""
    and list1[8] != ""
):
  print("Replay!")
```

Comment: the question says he tried that.

Comment: `not list1[0] == ""` is logically the same as `list1[0] != ""`.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right. When I setup a reproduction of the issue I must have made a mistake. Well, the good news for OP is that the if statement already in the Question is correct. The bug is elsewhere, if there is one.